# Min3D-White Texture Problem

Tags: android

I am getting my object as an .obj file which i exported from blender. I am trying to render it using the Min3D library. Now here's the problem. The object is rendered white even though I have applied textures. Can anybody help me out with this.?

Answer (score 1):

*.obj files have their textures information in a separate file, *.mtl. You need to add that one to your project as well. And possibly some image files referenced by *.mtl to your res/drawable directory

Answer (score 0):

As you will open your .mtl file, you will find a line like,

map_Kd camaro.jpg

where camaro.jpg is in my drawable folder.

instead you can place you generated files of UVW or Bitmaps of your 3d model into the drawable folder and then edit the .mtl file, like if u have bitmap named, "testpurpose.jpg" the add map_Kd testpurpose.jpg